# Combining two columns with OR to create a new column causes syntax error

Tags: t-sql

The following line is clipped from a SELECT statement

> (c.Prices || CHARINDEX('COD', cr.CRTermDesc) > 0)  AS ShowPrices

I've also tried this which returns the same error.

> (c.PricesOnPickingTicket || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('COD', cr.CRTermDesc) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS showPrices

Incorrect syntax near '|'

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Order1(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    CustId int NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.Cust (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    CRTerm int NOT NULL,
    Prices bit NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CRTerm (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    CRTermDesc nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    )   


INSERT INTO CRTerm
    VALUES (1,'COD')
    ,(2,'XYZ')

INSERT INTO Cust 
    VALUES (1,2,0)

INSERT INTO Order1
    VALUES (1,1)
    

SELECT 
    c.Prices = 1 OR CHARINDEX('COD', cr.CRTermDesc) > 0  AS showPrices
    FROM Order1 i
    INNER JOIN Cust c ON i.CustId = c.ID
    INNER JOIN CRTerm cr ON c.CRTerm = cr.ID 
    WHERE i.ID =  1

/*

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Completion time: 2023-10-12T07:33:31.7449093-07:00

*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Biegeleisen answered, the logical operation should be:

```
c.Prices = 1 OR CHARINDEX( 'COD', cr.CRTermDesc ) > 0
```

The result is a `boolean` and there lies the problem.

SQL Server supports the [`bit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.) There is a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

You can use a `case` expression to get from a `boolean` to another data type, e.g.:

```
cast( case when c.Prices = 1 OR CHARINDEX( 'COD', cr.CRTermDesc ) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
  as bit ) as ShowPrices
```

Comment: `As Tim Biegeleisen answered` ... why would you post the same answer as I did?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your answer had the correct logic, but you provided code that wouldn't work for the reason I explained in my answer. I could have commented on your answer explaining that `boolean` values cannot be returned as column values and suggesting a fix, or posted an answer that incorporated the explanation and provided credit to you for the logic. I'm confident that you can see that the answers differ and that attribution was given as appropriate. Should I remove my answer now?

Answer (score 1):

The logical or operator in SQL is `OR`, so try using this version:

```sql
c.Prices = 1 OR CHARINDEX('COD', cr.CRTermDesc) > 0 AS ShowPrices
```

Comment: The result is the same. I neglected to say that the c.Prices is a BIT column. I think this is the issue.

Comment: Edited assuming that `Prices` is a BIT column.

Comment: I feel that you fixed his syntax error but the logic of what he is trying to accomplish doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I want to return a synthetic column which is true if either prices is 1 or column CRTermDesc contains 'COD'

Comment: @user2443507 Then my answer should be working for your requirement.

Comment: I added to original posting above